# Which tense should be used with "while" here

Tags: grammar

A: Do you know how we spent the afternoon?

B: How?

A: All of us **chatted away** in the kitchen while Ben’s mother **showed** me how to cook his favorite food.

B: Great. Sounds like you had a fun time there, didn’t you?

The answer key says that we have to use past simple tense “chatted away and showed”. However why don’t we use past continuous? Is it possible to use other tenses?

For example:
All of us **were chatting** away in the kitchen while Ben’s mother **was showing** me how to cook his favorite food.

Comment: I think chatting and showing can be considered long activities, so I believe that your alternative is possible. What are the choices in the test?

Comment: Other choices in the test look weird. Thanks again for your help  Damkerng!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with the answer key. The past continuous sounds weird to me here.

I think you have to ask the question using the past continuous in order to answer in the past continuous.

> B: What were you guys doing this afternoon?
>
> A: All of us were chatting away in the kitchen while Ben’s mother was showing me how to cook his favorite food.
>
> B: Great. Sounds like you were having a fun time there, weren't you?